# What is best way to know type of sender object?

Tags: c++, oop

I have hierarchy of classes:

```
class A
{
};

class B : public A
{
};

class C : public B
{
};

class D : public A
{
};
```

and I have some function, which performs notification:

```
void notify(A* sender, const NotificationType notification)
{
}
```

My problem is how to find out exact type of sender object. I want to find elegant way to solve this problem. I don't like to use dynamic cast for these purposes. Possible way is to define enum within class A like:

```
enum ClassType
{
    CLASS_A,
    CLASS_B,
    CLASS_C,
    CLASS_D
};
```

and defining virtual method:

```
virtual ClassType get_type(void) const;
```

But this approach has bad scalability. Another way to keep this information in NotificationType, but it has bad scalability too.

P.S. I just want to use similar code:

I want to use similar code:

```
void notify(A* sender, const NotificationType notification)
{
    if (sender is object of A)
       new GuiA();
    else if (sender is object of B)
       new GuiB();
    else if (sender is object of C)
       new GuiC();
    else 
       new GuiD();
}
```

Comment: "how to find out exact type of sender object" If you need to know, you are doing it wrong.

Comment: Can you explain why you need to know the concrete type of `sender`?

Comment: It seems peculiar that you design the application to act polymorphically and then you feel the need to know the concrete type.

Comment: I just want to create appropriated class, which depends on type sender.

For example, lets classes A, B, C, D are model classes.
I want create appropriated Gui versions of these classes in notification method

Comment: @АлександрЛысенко you can use the following approach: class GuiFactory {public: virtual std::unique_ptr<Button> CreateButton() = 0; ... }; class A {public: virtual std::unique_ptr<GuiObject> CreateGuiObject(GuiFactory& factory) = 0;

Comment: Then add a virtual method `IAGuiInterface * createGuiVersion()` and let each sender create the appropriate Gui version polymorphically.

Answer (score 2):

If you want know type to persist your hierarchy, conside to use boost::TypeIndex (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/doc/html/boost_typeindex.html).

If you want know type to process different types in different manners, conside to use Visitor insted of type identifier or make abstract interface with virtual functions covers your needs.

**EDITED**

Your goal is to create different UI object for different types. You can use the following model to reach your goal:

```
class UIObject {...};
class UIObjectFactory {...};
class A {
public:
   virtual std::unique_ptr<UIObject> Create(UIObjectFactory& factory) = 0;
};

void OnNotify(A* sender) {
    auto ptr = sender->Create(GetUIFactory());
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To create a matching GUI object based on the concrete type of `sender`, you could pass a factory to some kind of factory method in `A`.

```
class A
{
public: 
    virtual Agui* createGui(GuiFactory& fac) = 0;
};

class GuiFactory
{
public: 
    virtual Agui* forB(B&) = 0;
    virtual Agui* forC(B&) = 0;
    virtual Agui* forD(D&) = 0;
};

class B : public A
{
public: 
    Agui* createGui(GuiFactory& fac)
    {
        return fac.forB(*this);
    }
};

void notify(A* sender, const NotificationType notification)
{
    // Use A interface...
    // Get the concrete GuiFactory from somewhere, and use it
    auto gui = sender->createGui(win32GuiFactory);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> and defining virtual method:

```
virtual ClassType get_type(void) const;
```

The easiest way to achieve this and get rid of scalability issue is to implement your `get_type()` member function in each class `A`, `B`, `C`, ... this way:

```
typedef uintptr_t ClassType;
virtual ClassType get_type() const
{
    static int dummy;
    return reinterpret_cast<ClassType>(&dummy);
}
```

A static variable `dummy` will be created for each class you add this member function, so that the return value identifies uniquely the class.